# Many lines in my prodecures are taken by declarations. Are there more efficient ways of doing this?

Tags: vba

I try to keep my procedures short. But often I need to reference several objects in a procedure and the declations alone end up occupying many rows. For example:

```
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Set wksSource = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wWorkspace")
Dim wksTarget As Worksheet
Set wksTarget = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wSaved")

Dim loWorkspace As ListObject
Set loWorkspace = wksOmdömeslistor.ListObjects("tWorkspace")

Dim sKey As String
Dim dMatchPosition As Double
```

In the above code I have spent 10 rows and the procedure doesn't do anything yet. It this the way it should be, or are the better ways of declaring variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your variables on one row this way:

```
Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksTarget As Worksheet, loWorkspace As ListObject, sKey As String, dMatchPosition As Double
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is more of a matter of coding style.  But I would recommend leaving it the way you have it.  However, I would probably group the variable declarations together.

```
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim wksTarget As Worksheet
Dim loWorkspace As ListObject
Dim sKey As String
Dim dMatchPosition As Double

Set wksSource = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wWorkspace")
Set wksTarget = GetSheetByCodename(ThisWorkbook, "wSaved")

Set loWorkspace = wksOmdömeslistor.ListObjects("tWorkspace")
```

Any programmer coming along would be able to read it and understand what is going on.  And, like @Radek stated, you can declare them on one line.  I would avoid doing that, though.

Comment: Its a lot easier to read and also easier to maintain because there is no "hoisting" of declarations in VBA. So this way, you don't have to think about the order of the declarations, only the flow of the code.